# Google Channel API - Socket not opening on some clients

Tags: google-app-engine, channel-api

I've been developing a simple chat application using the XMPP Service and the Channel service. I've been able to get it functioning correctly at home. However, when another user tries to access the site, the onOpen callback method is not being called. I've tried it from various locations using FireFox 3.6+ and Chrome and it has worked for me(at home, at work).

Is it possible that this is being blocked by a system administrator if the user is accessing it from a work location? Or could it be the browser being used? I had this person try with FireFox and Chrome. I wasn't there so I'm not certain which browser version was used. IE hasn't worked for me so I'm not concerned with that one.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's really more or less impossible to tell what the problem could be given the detail you've provided. Have you tried using an inspector/debug tool on the problem client's browser to see what is and isn't getting run? Is this just one user, or all users?

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your response. I don't have access to the users computer so I am unable to debug. This is more of a personal experimental project that I've been working on. (It's for the fiancée ha) So it's pretty much one user. The only quick test I performed was just calling alert() after each callback method was executed. I just had her note which popups were presented and the alert() for the open callback method was never executed. Unfortunately, I can't physically be there to debug the issue.

Comment: We really can't help with this much detail. If you can't debug it on their browser, we at least need to see the code you're trying to run. You haven't specified what browser they're using, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm. Since the Channel API uses Google Talk infrastructure, and an iframe pointed at the Google Talk frontends, the Channel API could be blocked by an administrator even if the main app isn't blocked. Specifically if a proxy is blocking talkgadget.google.com, the Channel API will fail to load.

I created a feature request for this here: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4764, feel free to vote it up.

Comment: Hi Moishe, thank you for your response. Are you the author of the google channel documentation/source code? If so, nice job! That makes complete sense because they block gchat there. That's a shame. Thank you very much. I went to the page and put in a vote. Hopefully a workaround will be in place in a future release.